# Is there a Google Docs (or Sheets) API to scroll the view?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

If I want to scroll to a particular paragraph in Google Docs, or a particular cell in Google spreadsheets, is there a way to do that via Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Google Doc Spreadsheet, you just need to set the active selection, the scroll is then done directly:

```
var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = file.getActiveSheet();
var row = LineToScrollTo;
file.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row,1));
```